# Skeletal animation on GPU for Android OpenGL ES

Tags: android, opengl-es, gpu

I'm implementing skeletal animation in my android phone, and here is how I do it:

1. Calcualte all bone transformation matrices on the CPU side
2. Create a float texture to store these matrices (so this is done at the beginning of each frame). The codes look like below:

   ```
   if(texID) {
       glDeleteTextures(1, &texID);
       texID = 0;
   }

   glGenTextures(1, &texID);
   glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texID);
   glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
   glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
   glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
   glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
   glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, p);
   ```
3. In vertex shader, fetch matrix from this texture and apply to vertex position

This approach works fine in my Motorola Milestone XT-701 using a POWERVR GPU. But when I run it on a Qualcomm snapdragon (SE Xperia X10i and Google Nexus one), there are many triangles disappeared (looks randomly), so it seems the model is flickering.

I also tried to reduce the scene complexity by rendering only one animated model, and the flicker become less but still exists. Does anyone know what I may be doing wrong? Is this some kind of synchronization problem?

You can see the [snapshots](http://www.dropbox.com/gallery/14175635/1/bug?h=d5e1e1) here (the first two pictures is correct, and the later two are wrong). The APK file of my grogram can be downloaded [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/14175635/GLES2.apk). (it does not require any permission so don't worry)

Here is the vertex shader I used:

```
struct light {
    lowp vec4    position;  // light position for a point/spot light or
                      // normalized dir. for a directional light
    lowp vec4    ambient_color;
    lowp vec4    diffuse_color;
    lowp vec4    specular_color;
    lowp vec3    spot_direction;
    lowp vec3    attenuation_factors;
    lowp float   spot_exponent;
    lowp float   spot_cutoff_angle;
    bool         compute_distance_attenuation;
};

struct material {
    lowp vec4    ambient_color;
    lowp vec4    diffuse_color;
    lowp vec4    specular_color;
    lowp vec4    emissive_color;
    lowp float   specular_exponent;
};

// uniforms used by the vertex shader
// uniform vec4 u_color;
uniform highp mat4     u_mvMatrix;
uniform highp mat4     u_projMatrix;
uniform bool           u_enable_lighting;
uniform light          u_light_state;
uniform material       u_material_state;
uniform bool           u_enable_texture;
uniform highp sampler2D   s_jointTex; // use highp for float texture

// attributes input to the vertex shader
// attribute lowp vec4 a_color;
attribute highp vec3    a_position;
attribute lowp vec3        a_normal;
attribute mediump vec2    a_texCoord;
attribute highp float    a_jointID;

// varying variables – input to the fragment shader
varying lowp vec4        v_front_color;
varying mediump vec2    v_texCoord;

vec2 mapTo2D(float idx)
{
    vec2 st = vec2(idx + 0.5, 0.5);
    return st / 256.0;
}

void main()
{
    mat4 joint = mat4(1.0);

    if(a_jointID >= 0.0)
    {
        float idx = a_jointID * 4.0;
        joint = mat4(    texture2D(s_jointTex, mapTo2D(idx)), 
                        texture2D(s_jointTex, mapTo2D(idx+1.0)), 
                        texture2D(s_jointTex, mapTo2D(idx+2.0)), 
                        texture2D(s_jointTex, mapTo2D(idx+3.0)) );
        gl_Position = (u_projMatrix * u_mvMatrix) * joint * vec4(a_position, 1.0); // hint compiler to extract uniform calculation
        // v_front_color = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    }
    else
    {
        gl_Position = (u_projMatrix * u_mvMatrix) * vec4(a_position, 1.0); // hint compiler to extract uniform calculation
        // v_front_color = vec4(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    }

    if(u_enable_lighting)
    {
        lowp vec4 computed_color = vec4(0.0);
        vec3 normal = normalize( vec3(u_mvMatrix * joint * vec4(a_normal, 0.0) ) );
        vec3 lightDir = normalize( vec3(u_mvMatrix * u_light_state.position) );
        float NdotL = max(dot(normal, lightDir), 0.0);

        computed_color += u_light_state.ambient_color * u_material_state.ambient_color + NdotL * u_light_state.diffuse_color * u_material_state.diffuse_color;

        if(NdotL > 0.0) {
            vec3 half_vec = normalize(lightDir + vec3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0)); // why?
            float NdotHV = dot(normal, half_vec);
            if(NdotHV > 0.0)
                computed_color += u_light_state.specular_color * u_material_state.specular_color * pow(NdotHV, u_material_state.specular_exponent);
        }
        v_front_color = computed_color;
    }
    else
        v_front_color = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0); // u_material_state.ambient_color; // TODO?

    v_texCoord = a_texCoord;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use matrix uniforms to pass the skeletal matrices?

Comment: The maximum number of matrix uniforms is restricted (at least it is in my device) so I don't think it is enough to hold all matrices for all models.

Comment: You shouldn't process all skeletal matrices at whole. Break down your model into smaller parts, which share only up to 4 bones. Keep in mind that you'll end up processing all matrices and then only create a superposition of only few of them, so passing the whole set is not very efficient as well. On regular OpenGL (not yet ES) there is the extension GL_ARB_uniform_buffer_object one could use instead of textures.

Comment: Try using glTexSubImage2D instead of deleting and re-creating the image each frame ?

Comment: Thanks! I will try your suggestions later to see if it works.

Comment: just an FYI: those conditionals in your shader are going to warp your GPU for sure: Mobile GPUs are very sensitive to warping. Even on powerful Adreno GPU, it will go from multi-core down to a single core because of those conditionals. You should see a huge (very noticeable) performance increase if you create multiple specific shaders instead of a big single shaders. Sometimes, optimizing with an if condition causes more damage than good. I hope this info helps you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Re-creating a texture each frame is not efficient. You can use the same `texID` and just call `glTexImage*` each frame.
2. Why don't you use 1D texture? It would remove a burden of tex-coord conversion to 2D.
3. Your joint matrix is 4x4, but you store it as 4 GL_RGBA vectors. This internal format does allow only [0,1] range, which is not appropriate for your task. Try using GL_RGBA_16f as internal format instead.

Comment: I re-create texture each frame because I read some article which says re-creating texture is actually more efficient than updating an existent texture in nowadays implementation. But I will try your suggestion, thanks.

Comment: Regarding the texture format, I know it should be RGBA_16F or RGBA_32F in OpenGL, but I think it is correct to use GL_RGBA in OpenGL ES. Actually, there seems no GL_RGA16F or 32F definition in OpenGL ES.

Comment: But do you realize that the values in GL_RGBA are clamped into [0,1] interval? If you do, then you should somehow pack your original FP values into there (like linear transform from [-2,2] into [0,1]).

Comment: To kvark: I understand what you say is true in desktop OpenGL, but in OES_texture_float definition (http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/OES/OES_texture_float.txt) it says GL_FLOAT texture type is 32-bits IEEE float format in OpenGL ES. (And it actually works in POWERVR GPU)

Comment: I tried to use glTexSubImage2D to update the existent texture, and it seems to solve the problem. Thanks!

Comment: @Johnson. It's good you've got it working. It's still confusing a bit about GL_FLOAT textures in GL ES. My mind can't accept the idea that the input type of `glTexImage*` controls the internal format, which has it's own parameter. Never mind....

Comment: There is a Limit on Opengl Texture size which is 2048 x 2048 on low end GPU's
if we use glTexSubImage1D we would not be able to scale after 2048 /16 = 128 Bones
assuming a model having more than 128 Bones using glTexSubImage2D would provide a scalable solution

Comment: @surya, each matrix is 4 vectors, so the maximum bone count would be 2048 / 4 = 512. That should be enough for everyone ;)

Comment: @kvark : my bad i forgot about RGBA Components and dvided it by 16 instead of 4 . Thanks for Correcting me ..